# how to get text on web browser use xpath C#?

Tags: c#, html

i have html code: not attribute...

```
<div 
   style="padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px; line-height: 20px; 
          text-align: center;">not found
</div>
```

how to get text "not found" with `xpath` or `GetElementsByTagName ("div")`?

Comment: add runat="server" to the div if you want it to access in your codebehind

Comment: @kumarch1: I don't think that is relevant, this sounds like a parsing question

Comment: if you want to access using javascript, then define an id to the div, for ex : <div id="div1" style="xxxx">not found</div> and you can access by using document.getElementById('div1')

Comment: thanks kumarch1! but how to add attribute to it? i only know set attribute :(